# How can I get from each matrix in a list the colname of the max value in each row in the matrix?

Tags: r

I hope the subject line is clear... I have a list of matrices. In each matrix, I'd like a vector of the column name that contains the max value for the row. A list of these vectors, actually. Simple example:

```
a = c(1,1,3)
b = c(7,2,1)
c = c(2,4,2)

d1 = cbind(a,b,c)

d = c(2,1,6)
e = c(1,4,2)
f = c(4,8,4)

d2 = cbind(d,e,f)

l = list(d1,d2)

l
[[1]]
     a b c
[1,] 1 7 2
[2,] 1 2 4
[3,] 3 1 2

[[2]]
     a b c
[1,] 2 1 4
[2,] 1 4 8
[3,] 6 2 4
```

I'm close.. this gets me the indexes of the max values:

```
lapply(l,function(y) apply(y, 1, function(x) which (x==max(x))))
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 1

[[2]]
[1] 3 3 1
```

But this is all I'm able to muster to get the column names:

```
lapply(l,function(y) apply(y, 1, function(y) colnames(y)[function(x) which (x==max(x))]))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

What I seek is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 'b', 'c', 'a'

[[2]]
[1] 'c', 'c', 'a'
```

In simpler expressions, `colnames(matrixFrameName)[expression returning indexes]` works as I'd expect; not in this case. Can someone help? Thx...

Comment: Your example is a list of matrices, not a list of data.frames...

Comment: Thx, edited; this is a simplified reproducible.. my application requires data frames and time series

Comment: rowwise computations on data.frames are slow and inefficient. (`apply` coerces data.frames to matrices. `data.frames` are stored by columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
lapply(l,function(y) colnames(y)[apply(y, 1, which.max)])

## [[1]]
## [1] "b" "c" "a"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "f" "f" "d"
```